# faster mysql query between 2 databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

**Looking to speed up query between 2 databases on same MySQL server**
Need to compare 001 value between db1.Source, db2.Source and return db2.Source.ID
This is a  **one-time query**  so I can let it cook for a while if there isn't a faster way to do it.

**db1.Source** (7,816,729 rows)

ID                    tag       value
ASP23409230     001     ASP23409230
ASP23409230     856     http://....
ASP23409230     245     Title of work
BCH20002930     001     BCH20002930
...

**db2.Source** (109,676,136 rows)
ID         tag    value
319778          001     ASP23409230
319778          856     http://....
319778          245     Title of work
319779
...

**Query**
SELECT t2.ID, t1.value, t2.value 
FROM   db1.Source t1, db2.Source t2
WHERE  t1.tag   = '001'
AND    t2.tag   = '001'
AND    t1.value = t2.value;

**Results** 
ID             value                  value
5369620     ASP71572/glmu  ASP71572/glmu
5370498     ASP73396/glmu  ASP73396/glmu

This is a bad query as LIMIT 20  takes about 30 seconds but it's what I've been able to cobble together so far. 
**Is there a faster way or should I set out on the 54 hour query (if that's even possible)**


Thank you for your time, efforts and insight.

Comment: You haven't shown the schema. I suspect you can probably speed things up by adding a couple of indexes

Comment: Please downvote questions atleast for new users. Nobody is perfect. Give some time for new users to settle down. If they are repeating mistakes again and again then definitely downvote questions.

Comment: tag is indexed - thinking about pushing the 001 field from db1 into a temp table in db2 - then running the compare and pulling out the IDs needed.

Comment: used INSERT INTO tempTable for the specific tag value giving me a 2 column table with 4 million rows to compare against vs. 100 million
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of querying all rows in both tables - setup smaller temporary tables with only the required data**:

INSERT INTO db1.temp1
SELECT s.recordID, s.value
FROM db1.sourceTable s
WHERE s.tag='001'

INSERT INTO db2.temp1
SELECT s.recordID, s.value
FROM db1.sourceTable s
WHERE s.tag='001'

Then using the 2 temp tables with about 4% of the original rows

SELECT t2.recordId, t2.value, t1.value
FROM db1.temp1 t1, db2.temp2 t2
where t1.value = t2.value

I had originally thought the query was slow due to them being in separate databases. It was the large number of rows it had to iterate over. Also the TAG column was not indexed.

Found the changing to a composite index of value, recordId also increased look up time.

Thanks for your help and insights.